# Selected Dropdown data will not display in another page

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a dropdown bar that is displayed using php.

```
<select id = "equipment" name="dropdwn" class="form-control">
    <option selected="" disabled="">Select Equipment</option>
    <?php
        $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT resource_name From resources WHERE resource_type = 'EQUIPMENT';");
        $row = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
            echo "<option name = 'equipment' value ='". $row['resource_name'] ."'>" .$row['resource_name'] ."</option>" ;
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

So I want to display the data that is being selected from that dropdown to another page.

I tried this and it does not work. It gives me an error "Notice: Undefined index: equipment"

```
<?php

include('dbconnector.php');

 $equipment = $_POST['equipment'];
 echo $equipment;
?>
```

If you could help me I would really appreciate it. Thanks ahead!

Comment: your select box name is `dropdwn` and not `equipment`. Use `$_POST['dropdwn']`.

Answer (score 1):

Change select name to **equipment**:

See below:

```
<select id = "equipment" name="equipment" class="form-control">
    <option selected="" disabled="">Select Equipment</option>
    <?php
        $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT resource_name From resources WHERE resource_type = 'EQUIPMENT';");
        $row = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
            echo "<option name = 'equipment' value ='". $row['resource_name'] ."'>" .$row['resource_name'] ."</option>" ;
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir. Thought the option tag was the one needed to have the name of equipment. anyway, thanks!

Comment: @Anthony.Jay, if this answer works for you, you should consider to accept this answer as solution.

Answer (score 1):

There are many selectors for HTML form elements

1) `id` -> used for css and javascript purposes (unique for each element).

2) `class` -> used for css and javascript purposes (multiple elements can have same class).

3) `name` -> This selector is very important. When we get our HTML form submitted to PHP, the elements are accessed with this selector.

For example:

```
<form method="post"...>
<input name="student" type="text" id="id_student"/>
...
```

If we submit the above form, in PHP we will the texbox value through:

`$_POST['student']`

**So, please correct your `name` attribute of drop down to make the page working.**